# Permutation Groups Containing non-commuting $p$-cycles

Tags: gr.group-theory, galois-theory

I noticed that the following is true, and that there is a reasonably elementary proof of it (in particular, the classification of finite simple groups is not needed). Let $G$ be a finite permutation group which contains two $p$-cycles which do not commute (where $p$ is any odd prime other than a Mersenne prime). Then $G$ is not solvable ( more precisely, $G$ has a non-Abelian composition factor of order divisible by $p$). Since the methods are reasonably elementary, I wonder if anyone has come across this or similar results (possibly in a Galois Theory context) and can point me to a reference?

For every Mersenne prime $p,$ there is a solvable permutation group $G$ of degree $p+1$ and order $p(p+1)$ which contains two non-commuting $p$-cycles.

(Later note: The analogous result is not true for $p^{2}$-cycles ($p$ prime). For $p=2$ take $G = S_{4}$ and for $p>2$ take $G$ to be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^{2}}.$ In each case, $G$ is a solvable (even nilpotent when $p$ is odd) permutation group containing two $p^{2}$-cycles which do not commute).

Comment: So you say e.g. that ${\rm A}_4$ is solvable because $3$ is a Mersenne prime?

Comment: Well, I don't say that, but the smallest exceptional case happens to be all of $A_{4.}$  But in general, if $p = 2^{n}-1$ is a prime, the the semidirect product $EC$ is solvable, where $E$ is elementary Abelian of order $2^{n}$ and $C$ acts on $E$ as a Singer cycle in ${\rm GL}(n,2).$ Furthermore, in its action on its Sylow $p$-subgroups by conjugation, $EC$ is a permutation group of degree $p+1$ and contains $p$-cycles which don't commute.

Comment: It won't be too surprising if Camille Jordan knew this result already (due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan's_theorem_(symmetric_group))

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik: Are you saying this is a consequence of Jordan's result? I don't see that, as I don't see that the question reduces easily to primitive groups; in any case, there is something to do in degree p,p+1, p+2, as the exceptions show. If you are saying Jordan might have known the result, who can say he didn't? While the methods I use are elementary, they are 20th century representation theoretic, not permutation group-theoretic, but there might be an easier method. Also note that PSL(2,p) has a permutation rep of degree p+1 and SL(2,p−1) has one of degree p if p is  Fermat

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I think a permutation group $G=\langle \sigma, \tau \rangle$ generated by two non-commuting $p$-cycles *is* primitive: If $\Delta$ is a block, then $\Delta \cap \operatorname{Mov} \sigma$ is empty or a block for $\langle \sigma \rangle$, and the same holds for $\tau$. By going through the different possibilities, I get that $\Delta$ must be trivial (or did I forget a case?). Of course, degrees p, p+1, p+2 remain. (I would be interested in a hint or sketch of your proof, by the way.)

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I'm not saying it might be a consequence. I meant to say that perhaps some part of it might be known to him, perhaps if you omit the corner cases of degree being close to p. Also, do you know a transitive imprimitive permutation group containing two non-commuting p-cycles?

Comment: @FriederLadisch : just a remark that "generated" is important here. It seems that you might have primitive action on each block this way (and this is indeed a reduction to the primitive case, more or less).

Comment: @FriederLadisch: Need to prove G not p-solvable. Suppose oherwise. Can assume G = <x,y> for non-disjoint p-cycles& that deg G < 2p, G transitive. Hence <x> and <y> are Sylow. Op(G) = 1, Op'(G) is not 1.Then Hall-Higman type arguments get to G = <x>E, where E is elementary or special q-group some prime q ( NB x centralizes every proper x-invariant subgroup of E). H = point stabilizer, corefree. Can eliminate E non-Abelian with care as H meets Z(E) \leq Z(G)  trivially in that case. Case E Abelian leads to H = <x>, [G:H] = p+1 = |E|, so p is Mersenne.

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik: It is (maybe!) interesting to note that while Jordan's result generalizes to cycles of prime power length (possibly with small exceptions), this result does not. It fails already for cycles of length $p^{2}$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I guess it's due to Frieder's primitivity argument really needing prime length. Anyhow, it seems that Jordan's result can often tell you more about groups in your theorem.

Comment: @ Dima Pasechnik : There is not much of what I proved that is not covered by Jordan and Burnside together.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I don't understand your last comment. Unless I made an error, my answer shows that in the non-Mersenne case $\langle x,y\rangle$ is simple, which is more than you asked for.

Comment: @Peter Mueller: My last comment was directed to Dima Pasechnik. Perhaps there is some subtlety of language, but the point of what I said was basically that (after what you and Frieder Ladisch wrote), only the Mersenne prime case was not covered by Jordan and Burnside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Fixed several inaccuracies, many thanks to Frieder Ladisch for spotting them:*

Let $x$ and $y$ be two non-commuting $p$-cycles, $G=\langle x,y\rangle$, and $G$ be considered as a transitive permutation group on the support $\Omega$ of $G$.

We show that either $\text{AGL}_1(\mathbb F_q)\le G$ for a Mersenne prime $q$, or $G$ is simple non-abelian.

*Proof.* $G$ is primitive (as pointed out by Frieder Ladisch already). This can be seen as follows: Let $\Delta$ be a block of a non-trivial block system. The action of the $p$-cycle $x$ on the block system is trivial, for otherwise $x$ would move $p\lvert\Delta\rvert>p$ points. On the other hand $G$ transitively moves the blocks, a contradiction.

Next we show that $G$ is doubly transitive. This follows from Burnside's classical theorem if $\lvert\Omega\rvert=p$. If $\lvert\Omega\rvert>p$, then the pointwise stabilizer in $G$ of the points fixed by $x$ is transitive (via $x$) on the remaining points. By [Jordan's Theorem](http://books.google.de/books?id=4bNj8K1omGAC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=%22jordan%20set%22%20doubly%20transitive&source=bl&ots=q4i_hG76Rd&sig=R-OGPQCPeMKXGvgBcoWjoBFPz6c&hl=de&sa=X&ei=klmpU4isLMj44QTrlICoCg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22jordan%20set%22%20doubly%20transitive&f=false) on primitive groups with Jordan sets we again see that $G$ is doubly transitive.

Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. By Burnside, $N$ is either (a) elementary abelian and regular, or $N$ is (b) simple, primitive, and not regular. The Mersenne exceptions follow from looking at $p$-cycles in $\text{GL}_m(q)$ where $n=q^m$ for a prime $q$: Such a $p$-cycle fixes $q^r<q^m$ points, hence $p=q^r(q^{m-r}-1)$. We obtain $r=0$ and $q=2$. By Schur's Lemma, we can identify $\langle x\rangle$ with the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_q$. This yields $\text{AGL}_1(\mathbb F_q)\le G$ as claimed. (If one uses [Kantor's paper on Singer cycles](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693%2880%2990214-8), then one gets more precisely the possibilities $G=\text{AGL}_1(\mathbb F_q)$, $\text{A$\Gamma$L}_1(\mathbb F_q)$, and $\text{AGL}_m(\mathbb F_2)$. However, that paper relies on a wrong paper of Cameron/Kantor, see [here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/odds/antiflag.pdf).)

Now assume case (b). We show that $G=N$, so $G$ is actually simple. In order to do so, we show that $p$ divides the order of $N$. Note that $\lvert\Omega\rvert<2p$, so $p^2$ does not divide $\lvert N\rvert$, hence $x,y\in N$ in this case.

The case $p=\lvert\Omega\rvert$ is clear.

So $p<\lvert\Omega\rvert$ from now on. We let $\omega$ be a fixed point of $x$, and set $\Omega'=\Omega\setminus\{\omega\}$.

First suppose $p=\lvert\Omega\rvert-1$. The point stabilizer $N_\omega$ is a normal subgroup of $G_\omega$. As $G_\omega$ is transitive on $\Omega'$, all orbits of $N_\omega$ on $\Omega'$ have equal length. But $\lvert\Omega'\rvert=p$, so these orbit lengths are either $1$ or $p$. The former cannot hold, because then $N$ were regular on $\Omega$. Thus  $N$ is doubly transitive on $\Omega$, so $p=\lvert\Omega\rvert-1$ divides $\lvert N\rvert$.

If $p<\lvert\Omega\rvert-2$, then $N=\text{Alt}(\Omega)$ by Jordan, so $G=N$ again.

If $p=\lvert\Omega\rvert-2$, then $G_\omega$ contains the cycle $x$ of length $p=\lvert\Omega'\rvert-1$ on $\Omega'$, so $G_\omega$ it is doubly transitive on $\Omega'$. The argument in the case $p=\lvert\Omega\rvert-1$ shows that $N_\omega$ is either doubly transitive on $\Omega'$, or regular. In the former case $p=\lvert\Omega'\rvert-1$ divides $\lvert N_\omega\rvert$, hence $G=N$ again. In the latter case, $N$ is sharply doubly transitive on $\Omega$, which implies that $N$ has a regular normal subgroup, contrary to $N$ being simple. (For this last step, simple counting suffices. One does not need Frobenius' theorem about the existence of Frobenius kernels.)

Comment: The case $|\Omega|=p$ is actually somewhat easier: if $N$ is a minimal subgroup of $G$, then $N$ is transitive and thus $x, y\in N$, so $G=N$ is simple. In the general "almost simple" case, is it clear that the order of the unique minimal normal subgroup $N$ is divisble by $p$ (and thus $G=N$ simple), without invoking Hall-Higman or similar arguments? Because this is what Geoff's argument shows: Either $G$ is simple, or $G \leq \operatorname{AGL}(m,2)$, where $p=2^m-1$.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't follow your argument in the case $n=p+1$. I think this is exactly the case where one needs something like Hall-Higman reduction to see that if $p$ does not divide $N$, then $N$ is not non-abelian simple. Also I don't know what you mean by "repeating the argument with $N$ instead of $G$" in case $p=n-2$. In that case, I have the following argument: if $N$ is $p'$, then $C_N(x)$ is transitive on the two elements fixed by $x$ (Lemma of Glauberman on coprime action), thus $N$ contains a 2-cycle, contradiction since $G\leq A_n$.

Comment: @Frieder Ladisch: Thanks for pointing out the errors. I'm still a little in haste, but I hope things are somewhat correct now.

Comment: @Peter,Frieder : Once one has reduced the original problem to primitive groups (which can't be done with prime power order cycles), it seems that everything comes down to classical permutation group theory a la Jordan and Burnside, which is not how my original proof went (or, indeed, how I tend to think). I find the argument a little unclear in the case $n = p+1.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I rewrote the arguments. Hope the case $n=\lvert\Omega\rvert=p+1$ is clearer now.

Comment: @Peter Müller: I find your argument for $p= |\Omega|-1$ very simple and elegant. In case $p = |\Omega|-2$ I think one still needs to say why $N_{\omega}$ can not be regular on $\Omega'$, for example, because otherwise $N$ would be a doubly transitive Frobenius group, thus not simple.

Comment: (And in the Mersenne case, also $G= \operatorname{ASL}(m,2)$ and $G= \operatorname{A\Gamma L}(1,2^m)$ is possible.)